# How to dynamic_cast and test for success for a reference

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to downcast from `VPN` to `OpenVPN` (which obviously inherits from `VPN`) like this:

```
void to_json(json &j, const VPN &p)
        {
            if (auto& pp = dynamic_cast<const OpenVPN&>(p))
            {
                to_json(j, pp);
            }
            else
            {
                //throw
            }
        }
```

However at `auto& pp =`  I get `expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)`. Usually it works for pointers. Is there a way to test if the dynamic_cast worked? What if I have multiple subtypes of `VPN` and need to find which one this specific `VPN&` is?

I'd use pointers but I'm implementing `void to_json(json &j, const VPN &p)` which is for a [json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) so I'm forced to use references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write simply:

```
void to_json(json &j, const VPN &p)
{
    to_json(j, dynamic_cast<const OpenVPN&>(p));
}
```

If the `dynamic_cast` succeeds, then `to_json` is called. If the `dynamic_cast` fails, a `std::bad_cast` exception is automatically thrown by the runtime. Since you don't seem intent on reacting to the exception in this context, you don't even need a try-catch block. You can just let it propagate up to the caller.

Comment: hmm but I intend to add,in the future, other types, like `MicrosoftVPN`, `CiscoVPN`, etc. My idea is to test if the casting worked. If not, jump to the next casting, until I find which type `VPN&` really is. Is it `OpenVPN`? Is it `MicrosoftVPN`? Is it `CiscoVPN`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs you shouldn't do that. You should add a virtual to_json method to the base class and implement it in the derived classes. If you absolutely must switch on types, use the pointer form of dynamic_cast. It returns a null pointer when it fails.

Comment: I agree, but this json library (which is really good), wont accept virtual methods I guess. As you see here: https://github.com/nlohmann/json#basic-usage it needs a simple function called `to_json` that accepts the type as parameter. I can't use pointer and can't use methods (at least I dont think it's possible)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs you may write: `if (const auto* pp = dynamic_cast<const OpenVPN*>(&p)) { to_json(j, *pp); }`